# Copyrights of an application with similar name to another application

Tags: copyright, open-source-software

i has writing a php framework that its features is most important features that are exists in codeigniter and laravel and very very another features that is not exists in another frameworks. it's a full framework with many features and capablities. actually my framework is not complatly global and i wanna create it for my country programmers but non-iranians can use it and it's not dedicated to iran and iranians. becuase in iran we haven't a powerful framework such as CI or Symfony or ... that be iranian and have an iranian community to my compatriots could ask their questions with their own language on it. becuase as i'm a codeigniter developer, i know the problems of all of my compatriots programmers so about 6 month ago started writing my framework and from first i called it LaunchPad and its terminal countdown. actually the LaunchPad terminal (countdown) is similar to CI Spark or Laravel artisan

and about my question: i know we have an application with launchpad name, that all of us known what is its activity area. if i call my framework to launchpad, it's incorrect ? i mean this work break the rights of copyright or trademarks rules or not and it's ok ?

Comment: Not copyright, but trademark.  Do you plan to make your framework available outside Iran?  If not, the matter will be much simpler.

Comment: @phoog thank you for answer. my framework (my country framework) is not dedicated to iran country and iranians and it's open for all whole world. but reason of this project is for that iran has own framwork and socity. something like StackOverflow and StackExchange that iranians could talk with persian language and solving their problems on it. i wanna create this community with my own framework. but non-iranians can use my framework and have activity in my community. my framework name is launchpad and it's terminal is countdown. it's possible that i have problem about it in trademarks rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Esteki is correct.  Your copyright rights attached upon completion of your program; it’s considered a literary work. No registration is needed for the protection, but it is always helpful to make your rights searchable in case you need to protect your work in the future. If your program is substantially different from the other program and could not be confused with the other LaunchPad then you might be able to get away with using it. You need to contact an intellectual property (IP) attorney who has experience with both Iranian law and international IP issues.  With the virus issue now, they should be more inclined to have a video conference with you. So, location issues would be less of a problem.  My personal opinion is that you should find a different trademark and save yourself any possible legal headaches since it appears that they are similar and could be confused with each other.  Again, an IP attorney can help you with all of that. I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: tnx for your kind. and welcome to SE communities